# C++ overload map [ ] operator

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, overloading, brackets

I have 2 overloaded operator declaration that I need help understanding.

```
template<class KEY, class T>
const T& Map<KEY, T>::operator [](const KEY& key) const { }
```

and

```
template<class KEY, class T>
T& Map<KEY, T>::operator [](const KEY& key) { }
```

the first `[]` is used to access the value/return value, i.e `std::cout<<m["x"]<<std::endl;`

the second `[]` is for assignment, i.e `m["x"] = 1;`

The question I have pertains to the 2nd `[]`. If I were to do `m["z"] = 10`, how does `10` get stored as the value associated with key `z`? Looking at the function declaration, I only see the key, not value.

I tried doing `m_value = T();`, but I'm not sure what T() is.

Thank you

Comment: you ask how m["z"] = 10 works behind the scenes?

Comment: `std::cout<<m["x"]<<std::endl;` uses the non-const (2nd) version when `m` is not const.

Comment: the 2nd (what you call "is for assignment") operator can only be applied to non-const Map objects. The result is a non-const reference to a value type T. 
On this non-const T now the T::operator=(const T& tparm) can be applied: that means the assignment operator of T is used to assign tparm to the T& you get from the 2nd operator.

Comment: yes, how m["z"] = 10 works. How does overloading the `[]` operator work. I'm not sure what the purpose of returning a reference is when in the body of the function I return the map's value

Comment: @Steven: The purpose of returning a reference to the map's value is to allow assignment to that reference to change that value. That's how references work.

Comment: I have something along the lines of `map[length++] = pair<KEY,T>(key,T());` A pair being defined as a (key,value). For some reason, when I do `hm["a"] = 5`, `a` is assigned `5`, but when I do `std::cout<<hm["a"]<<std::endl`, the `a` is now assigned `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a reference:

```
template<class KEY, class T>
T& Map<KEY, T>::operator [](const KEY& key) { }
 ^ that means "reference"
```

That will be a reference to an object stored in the map. Assigning to the reference will assign to that object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the const. In theory you could use the 2nd for output too (and may be doing as they are both basically the same function with the same parameters. But that's not your question :)

All your 2nd "[]" is doing is giving you access to the item stored at "z", the assignment is done using the "=" operator which you have not shown to be overloaded here.

Therefore the 10 gets stored using the standard version of the "=" operator using your 2nd "[]" operator as the access method.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not 'in theory', but whenever the map is not const.

Comment: The provided overloaded = is not useful because it is used to copy one map to another. Going back to the reference "&" as mentioned above, I'm still not quite sure how I would use it. I found an example where someone did something along the lines of `map[length+1] = pair(KEY,T>(key,T());` Would you know what purpose `T()` serve?

Comment: presumably T() is the default constructor of Class T. in your original question you said its a pair of <Class Key, Class T>. So the only thing I can think is that T() is the constructor for a new instance maybe?

Comment: If this has answered your question then can't you accept the answer? Thanks, Mal

Comment: The answer should mention that the method returns a reference to an object, which can be changed.